# Does iOS delay peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests: and peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest:?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use an iPhone as a peripheral to communicate with a micro controller (BLE chip in question is the BGM113). After connecting from the MCU, the MCU sends a couple of read and write requests for characteristics serially. Each request takes only a few ms in the MCU. On the iPhone side, responding to each request also only takes a few ms in the relevant methods (`peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` and `peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest:`).

Still, I have roughly 500ms delay between each request. I have a support request running with the bluetooth chip manufacturer to clarify, but my gut feeling tells me that the fruity company is to blame...

**Can anyone confirm such delays when reading or writing characteristics?**

(more details: all characteristics are in the same service, read and write may happen on the same characteristic serially, there are several characteristics that I operate on.)

Comment: What is your connection interval?

Comment: Kept them at the defaults, but they are not documented. What would you recommend for min and max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delay will be between 1 and 2 times the connection interval, so you set the connection interval to match your maximum delay requirement. Note that the energy consumption for the radio is linear to the inverse of the connection interval though.